# What are the extra topics created when creating and debezium source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Q1) Following is my config which I used while creating the kafka connector for MySQL source.

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
  "database.user": "cdc_user",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "10.49.115.X:9092,10.48.X.211:9092,10.X.178.121:9092,10.53.4.X:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform",
  "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "table.whitelist": "seller_platform.Contacts, seller_platform.EmailVerificationConfigs, seller_platform.financial_account_tag, seller_platform.HolidayConfigs, seller_platform.Preferences, seller_platform.Sellers",
  "database.hostname": "something.cloud.in",
  "database.password": "ABCDE",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.connector",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "database.whitelist": "seller_platform",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
}


curl -s --location --request GET "http://10.24.18.167:80/connectors/cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.connector/topics" | jq '.'
{
  "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.connector": {
    "topics": [
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.Sellers",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.HolidayConfigs",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.EmailVerificationConfigs",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.Contacts",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.Preferences",
      "__debezium-heartbeat.cdc.fkw.supply.mp",
      "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_platform.financial_account_tag"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why cdc.fkw.supply.mp and __debezium-heartbeat.cdc.fkw.supply.mp topic gets created?

I see some garbage data inside these 2 topics.

Q2)

Is there any rest api to know the kafka connect converter configuration on the worker server?
If there is no API, then what is the path of the the configuration file where we store all worker properties?

This is the link of the worker properties:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html

```
curl -s --location --request GET "http://10.24.18.167:80"         
                                                            
{"version":"6.1.1-ccs","commit":"c209f70c6c2e52ae","kafka_cluster_id":"snBlf-kfTdCYWEO9IIEXTA"}%
```

Comment: The description of the heartbeat topic should be documented somewhere, but both seem related to your `database.server.name` config. What garbage data are you referring to?

Comment: And no, worker properties are not available over REST. You can find converter properties in the logs, though, or of course, you can override and set your own

Comment: I got the answer, actually the debezium connector stores the kafka topic to which it wants to send the heartbeat. the another topic is to store the schema changes.

Comment: Now I got a new problem. The connectors are running and I am trying to delete the schema in schema registry 
``` curl -s --location --request DELETE 'http://10.24.17.179/subjects/cdc.fkw.supply.spf.spf.claim-key?permanent=true' 
{"error_code":500,"message":"Error while deleting the subject cdc.fkw.supply.spf.spf.claim-key"}```

when I try ```curl -s --location --request DELETE 'http://10.24.17.179/subjects/cdc.fkw.supply.mp.miami.working_hour-key/versions/1'
{"error_code":50004,"message":"Master not known."}```

Comment: Please answer your initial question below with that comment, and open a new post for new errors.

Comment: This is what I am getting again. I tried to delete the schema for which there is no connector running.

Comment: Unless the table schema has changed with an incompatibility, there is no need to delete data from the registry

Comment: yes asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600796/unable-to-delete-subject-in-schema-registry-confluent

Answer (score 1):

A1)

The heartbeat topic stores the details of all the kafka topics which the connector is using so that the connector can send heartbeat to it.

the database.server.name value named topic is created to store any schema changes that takes place in the database.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-schema-change-topic