# Confluent schema registry - Master not known when trying to delete subject version

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

When i try to delete a subject I get,

```
curl -s --location --request DELETE 'http://10.24.17.XXX/subjects/cdc.fkw.supply.spf.spf.claim-key?permanent=true'
{"error_code":500,"message":"Error while deleting the subject cdc.fkw.supply.spf.spf.claim-key"}%
```

I tried this way as well,

```
curl -s --location --request DELETE 'http://10.24.17.179/subjects/cdc.fkw.supply.mp.miami.working_hour-key/versions/1'
{"error_code":50004,"message":"Master not known."}
```

Basically there are 3 servers behind the elb which have SR. Following is the configuration on one of the server.

```
listeners=http://10.X.X.76:8081 
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://10.XXX:9092,PLAINTEXT://10.XXX:9092,PLAINTEXT://10.XXXX.1:9092,PLAINTEXT://1XXXX.69:9092 
kafkastore.topic=_schemas 
debug=false 
master.eligibility=true
```

Comment: Do you have access to the Schema Registry logs or are you the admin of it? The solution would include editing its config. You cannot fix this from the client side

Comment: No, I don't have access, which configs need to be edited? Do you have any reference URL to follow? So that I can ask the admins to delete it.

Comment: The error indicates there are multiple registries running, maybe for fault tolerance, so you appear to be reaching the wrong one via a proxy. The `listeners` and `leader.eligibility` settings would be a start

Comment: Log:
```Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.UnknownMasterException: Register schema request failed since master is unknown
 at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:546)
 at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:263)```

Comment: the mentioned config exists same on all servers.
```listeners=http://XX.XX.XX:8081
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://1something
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false
master.eligibility=true```

Comment: When i run them on each server there is a different error,
Server 1) ```{"error_code":500,"message":"Error while deleting the subject cdc.fkw.supply.mp.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist-value"}```
Server 2 and 3) ```{"error_code":40401,"message":"Subject 'cdc.fkw.supply.mp.fk_sp_generic_checklist.enti' not found."}```

Comment: 1) In the latest version of the registry, the property is `leader.eligibility` rather than master 2) If you are using a ELB, you may need `proxy.host`+`proxy.port` configured. 3) Seems like server 2 and 3 are working fine, assuming you spell the subject name correctly

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your response,  but the subject exists and the error which I see for 2 and 3 says that subject not found.

Comment: `cdc.fkw.supply.mp.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist-value` is not the same as `cdc.fkw.supply.mp.fk_sp_generic_checklist.enti` (it got cut off somehow, and the quotes in the error show that)