# Debezium topics and schema registry subject descriptions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When I create Debezium connector, it creates many kafka topics and schema registry subjects.

I am not sure about what these topics and subjects are what is its purpose

My connector configuration:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
  "database.user": "XXXXX",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "XX:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "table.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist",
  "database.hostname": "abc.kcloud.in",
  "database.password": "XXXXXX",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace1.fk_sp_generic_checklist.connector",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "database.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
}
```

Subjects got created in schema registry:

```
1) __debezium-heartbeat.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist-key
2) __debezium-heartbeat.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist-value
3) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist-key
4) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist-value
5) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist-key
6) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist-value
7) tr.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist-value
```

The Kafka topics which got created are:

```
1) __debezium-heartbeat.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist
2) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist
3) cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist.fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist
4) history.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the purpose of the subjects and topics based on my above connector configuration?
2. What if I deleted my connector and again created a new one with the same name and same database.tables? Will the data ingest from the beginning?
3. Is there a way to delete the entire connector and create a new one with the same name but as a fresh connector? (This is in case I messed up with some settings and then want to delete the existing data and create a fresh one)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of the [...] topics based on my above connector configuration

Obviously, Debezium reads each database-table into one topic.

Otherwise, you seem to have asked this - [What are the extra topics created when creating and debezium source connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599561/what-are-the-extra-topics-created-when-creating-and-debezium-source-connector)

---

> [purpose of the] subjects

The subjects are all made because of your `key.converter` and `value.converter` configs (which are not shown). They are optional, for example, if you configured JSONConverter instead of using the Schema Registry.

You have a `-key` and a `-value` schema for each topic that that Connector is using that map to the Kafka record key-value pairs. This is not unique to Debezium. The `tr.cdc...` one seems to be extra, and doesn't refer to anything in the config shown, nor has an associated topic name.

Sidenote: Avro keys are usually discouraged unless you have a specific purpose for it; keys are often ID's or simple values that are used for comparison, partitioning, and compaction. If you modify a complex Avro object in any way. E.g. add/remove/rename fields, then that results in problems for consumers that expected that record to be in-order with previous records of some other field-value will have issues.

> 2. Delete and re-create ... Will it start from the beginning

With the same name, no. Source Connectors use the internal Kafka Connect offsets topic. Debezium History Topic also comes into effect, I assume. [You would need to manually change these events](https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/) to reset the database records to read.

> 3. Delete and start fresh.

Yes, deletes are possible. Refer the Connect REST API `DELETE` HTTP method. Then read above about (2).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71355608/debezium-connector-task-is-in-unassigned-state

Please help me on this.